# Difference between Caching and Slab Allocator

Tags: memory-allocation

I've seen the term caching allocator and slab allocator used in discussions about allocation strategies, and would like to understand the difference between them.

I can see some resources on slab allocators, but nothing on caching allocators. What is a caching allocator and how is it different from a slab allocator?

Also, if you can point me to some resources on allocators in general that would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

A caching allocator is an allocator that keeps a cache of released objects for later allocation.

When an object is needed, memory is allocated and then an object is initialised, or constructed, in that area of memory. When an object is no longer needed, it is usually destroyed and then freed.

If this is a type of object that is frequently allocated/deallocated, and the type of object has an expensive constructor or destructor, then it makes sense to keep a cache of objects in their constructed state.

The slab allocator is one specific implementation of a caching allocator.